# Need explanation about displacment and get_rect

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am following a tutorial. I wrote this :

```
import pygame 
import time 
import os 
import random 
import neat 



WIN_WIDTH = 600
WIN_HEIGHT = 800 


Bird_imgs = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird1.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird2.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird3.png")))]
Base_img = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs,", "base.png")))
Pipe_img = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs,", "pipe.png")))
Bg_img = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs,", "bg.png")))

class Bird:
    imgs = Bird_imgs
    Max_Rotation = 25
    Rot_Vel = 20
    Animation_Time = 5
    #Init
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tilt = 0
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.height = self.y
        self.img_count = 0 
        self.img = self.imgs[0] #It's the image from Bird_imgs (bird1)

    def jump(self):
        self.vel = -10.5
        self.tick_count = 0 
        self.height = self.y

    def move(self):
        self.tick_count += 1
        d = self.vel*self.tick_count + 1.5*self.tick_count**2

        if d >= 16:
            d = 16

        if d < 0:
            d -= 2

        self.y += d

        if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
            if self.tilt < self.Max_Rotation:
                self.tilt = self.Max_Rotation
        else: 
            if self.tilt > -90:
                self.tilt -= self.Rot_Vel


    def draw(self, win):
        self.img_count += 1

        if self.img_count < self.Animation_Time:
            self.img = self.imgs[0]
        elif self.img_count < self.Animation_Time*2:
            self.img = self.imgs[1]
        elif self.img_count < self.Animation_Time*3:
            self.img = self.imgs[2]
        elif self.img_count < self.Animation_Time*4:
            self.img = self.imgs[1]
        elif self.img_count == self.Animation_Time*4 +1:
            self.img = self.imgs[0]
            self.img_count = 0

        if self.tilt <= 80:
            self.img = self.imgs[1]
            self.img_count = self.Animation_Time*2

        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)
        new_rectangle = rotated_image.get_rect(center=self.img.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y)).center)
```

I understood almost everything. First, we import modules. We define the resolution. 
Then we load images and we scale them. We create a few variables in our class. We initialize...

But,

This line :

```
d = self.vel*self.tick_count + 0.5*(3)*(self.tick_count)**2
```

comes from a physic formula. But why 3 ?

Can you tell me what does :

```
if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
            if self.tilt < self.Max_Rotation:
                self.tilt = self.Max_Rotation
        else: 
            if self.tilt > -90:
                self.tilt -= self.Rot_Vel do ? And why these values ?
```

Can you explain to me these 2 lines :

```
rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)
        new_rectangle = rotated_image.get_rect(center=self.img.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y)).center)
```

? Especially the last one. 
Thank you.

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in dirrerent variables - it helps to understand code. Using `center=` usually means it tries to center one object on other object. After rotating image may have different size and its center can be in different place so it may try to put rotated image in the same place as original one.

Comment: When you looked up all that stuff in the `pygame` or `python` docs, did you understand the explanation of all the various components of those statements? If not, what specifically did you not understand? Try not to ask too many questions at once. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your first question is why the "3" in the kinematic equation in place of "a". Well, my guess is whoever wrote your simulation felt like a value of 3 for the acceleration constant worked the best visually.
2. It seems to me that "d" is the distance your bird falls from its height at the time of a previous jump. After every time you jump, you have to reset your height and "time" (tick_marks) and return to normal, kinematic, constant acceleration physics, and from there you can continually measure a height deviation from that point ("d"). If the "d" value is negative (ie you are still jumping upwards) or after the bird has fallen 50 pixels from the max_height setpoint, you set your tilt (angle) to a certain rotation amount. If it hasn't dropped that far yet, you are slowly tilting the bird every frame.
3. First line rotates the image object. The 2nd line is to determine WHERE the image should be bilted. Namely, you are creating a new surface with rectangular dimensions of the same area as the previous image and the same center (ie rotating the location).

I'll let you figure out which parts of the syntax refer to the actions above and why, but feel free to ask questions in the comments.